# NGNIX reverse proxy with client certificate

Tags: nginx, client-certificates, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have front end serverA and back end serverB. the actual application is hosted on serverB. When the client makes call to API, serverB will have to authenticate using client certificate that is sent by client.

We have installed Ngnix in serverA to proxy_pass the traffic received from clients to serverB. 
when the client make call to serverA with client certificate, the client certificate is not sent by Ngnix to serverB and due to this serverB reject the request from client.

Is there any way we can redirect the request to serverB along with client certificate that is originally sent by clients?

Below is my Ngnix configuration.

If Ngnix is not capable of doing this, is there any other opensource tool avaialable with this functionality?

```
server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  localhost;

        ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  cert.pem;

        ssl on;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            proxy_pass "https://localhost:8099";            
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the error message in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`?  Have you tried to specify your certificate path? e.g. `ssl_certificate             /etc/ssl/cert.pem;`

Comment: @Bruno there is no error currently with the above configuration. my question was about the client certificate.  when the clients make call to Ngnix localhost:443 along with client certificate, the same certificate is not passed to ServerB (https://localhost:8099) by Ngnix. how to pass the same certificate to serverB which actually sent by client to serverA.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, maybe late for that, but hope it helps.

You can proxy requests with client certificate by sending the variable [$ssl_client_cert](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#var_ssl_client_escaped_cert) in a request header when proxying to the back end serverB.